# Expand a function to power series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I have the following function and i try to expand it to a power series - 
$$F(x) = \frac{2x}{(x^2+1)^2}$$ 
around $X = 0$

I tried to substitute $t = -x^2$ and got stuck.
I would like to get some help , thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{1+x^2}=-\frac{2x}{(1+x^2)^2}
$$
So
\begin{align}
F(x)&=-\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{1+x^2}=-\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-x^2)^n=\\
&=-\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{2n}=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n 2n x^{2n-1}=\\
&=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}2(n+1)x^{2n+1}=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n}(n+1)x^{2n+1}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks , can u please also write the derivation of the power series? $\sum (-1)^n(x)^{2n}$

Answer (score 1):

We can also apply the *[binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* expansion.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{2x}{(x^2+1)^2}&=2x\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{-2}{n}x^{2n}\tag{1}\\
> &=2x\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+1}{1}(-1)^nx^{2n}\tag{2}\\
> &=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n(n+1)x^{2n+1}\\
> &=2x-4x^3+6x^5+\cdots
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In   (1) we apply the *binomial series expansion*
- In (2) we use the binomial identity
  \begin{align*}
  \binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{p-1}(-1)^q
  \end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{2x}{(1+x^2)^2}=2x\sum_{i=0}^\infty  (-1)^i (i+1)x^{2i}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^i 2(i+1)x^{2i+1}
$$